# Is it possible to send TCP packet to a specific port with scapy's send function?

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I am trying to send and receive an TCP packet with data on it. My current line of code for sending is:

`send(IP(src="1.1.1.1",dst="1.2.3.4")/TCP()/"Test")`

How would I specify a Port

Comment: Not going to happen. ICMP is a different protocol than TCP or UDP and doesn't have ports. So trying to send an IMCP packet to a port won't go well. See [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/a/309358/870242) for a more detailed answer

Comment: thx, I will update this question

Comment: `TCP(dport=425)` to specify a destination port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an simple idea:

```
port = random.randint(48620, 49150)
```

If you want to know what is port, go to:

https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/port-number

Thanks

Comment: These are number I decided or you can use other numbers